# TextBox resizes automatically when overflowed (in WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, textbox, overflow

I am trying to create a property panel, and I am using a listbox. I don't know another way of making a dynamic table, so this is what I did:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PropertyListTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />

            <ComboBox x:Name="combo"
                      Grid.Column="1"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding ComboItems}"
                      SelectedIndex="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                      Visibility="Hidden" />

            <TextBox x:Name="text"
                     Grid.Column="1"
                     Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
                     Visibility="Hidden" />
            <!-- ... More controls -->

        </Grid>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TypeString}" Value="Combobox">
                <Setter TargetName="combo" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <!-- ... More triggers -->
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The problem is this:

[image: Overflow]

When the textbox or the combobox overflows, it resizes automatically.
How can I disable this behavior? The width of the control should be adjusted depending on the width of the parent listbox... I don't want any horizontal scrollbars...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Then turn horizontal scroll bars off (disable) on the parent ListBox.

Comment: Wow, that was unexpectedly easy... I thought that something more complicated had to be done, that disabling horizontal scroll bars would only hide them... Well, thank you very much.

Comment: Where is the parent listbox in the OP's question?